# Using two array expressions in single forEach loop

Tags: php

If I use two array expressions with two values, I do not get an error but I also get absolutely no output:

**NOT WORKING**:

```
<?php foreach ($zones as $zone) {
    $body = $zone->get_body();
    $domain_name = $zone->get_domain_name();
    $name = $zone->get_name();

    foreach ($domains as $domain) {
        $status = $domain->get_status();

        if (strstr($body, $ip)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $domain_name . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $status . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $body . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

So I need to be able to target the $status variable also which uses $domain instead of $zones

When I use the below code for only zones, everything works fine and I get data that outputs.

**WORKING**:

```
<?php foreach ($zones as $zone) {
        $body = $zone->get_body();
        $domain_name = $zone->get_domain_name();
        $name = $zone->get_name();

        if (strstr($body, $ip)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $domain_name . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $body . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $count++;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is `var_dump($domains);`?

Comment: If you're not getting any output, it means `$domains` is an empty array.

Comment: Where is the code that sets `$domains`? Why are you going through the same list of domains for every zone?

Comment: Is `$domains` supposed to depend on `$zone`? Maybe you forgot to reassign it each time through the first loop.